# Spectrum Color-Picker not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, color-picker, spectrum

I'm using Spectrum Color picker in a javascript project I'm working on. https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/
It works fine in FireFox, but not in Internet Explorer. The fancy color picker popup degrades to a simple text input field. Here is the section of code that creates the input field:

```
function updateTables() {
$("#tableTwo tbody").empty();
for (var i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
    //var pColor = new RGBColor();
    var pColor = rgbaToHex(polygons[i].color);
    $("#tableTwo tbody").append('\n<tr '
                                + (selectedPoly == i ? 'style="color:white;background-color:red"' : '')
                                + '><td><input onchange="changeGeometryName(' + i + ')"'
                                + (selectedPoly != i ? 'onfocus="polySelectedFromTable(' + i + ')"' : '') + 'type="text" size="11" '
                                + 'id="polygonName' + i + 'Input"  value="' + polygons[i].name + '" /></td>' + "<td><input type='color'"
                                + ' onchange="setColor(' + i + ')" id="color' + i + '" value="' + pColor + '"/></td>' + "</tr>");
}
```

}

And then I have these two lines in my HTML file:

```
<script src='spectrum.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='spectrum.css' />
```

The documentation says the input will degrade to a text input if javascript isn't working, but I know that can't be the issue sense the rest of the project works fine. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh hi!

So firstly, the spectrum documentation was a bit confusing about this so it took me a while to find, but the answer is actually really, really dumb once you find it:

You're not using spectrum.

So, firstly, the documentation says:

> If you just want to provide a polyfill for the native color input, the easiest way is to create an input with the type of color. Once a user's browser supports a native color control, it will opt to use their native control instead. [Spectrum Docs](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/#modes-input)

So, this is what we were trying to do, without realizing we weren't really using spectrum.  Instead, we were using the HTML 5 color input type spec, which isn't supported by IE (See [color input type support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-color))

So, to enable spectrum, we actually need to make a call to the spectrum library, and then it works:

```
$('#color' + id).spectrum({ color: pColor(, other-parameters-here)});
```